# jTextArea background not changing after setEnabled(false)

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtextfield, jtextarea

i have set setEnabled(false) for my jTextArea in a netbeans. The textarea is disabled but its background colour is not changing from white to a 'grayish' as expected. This only happens if i run my project from main class. It changes the background colour to a 'grayish' while running from the jForm containing the textArea. Why is this?

Comment: post some code please.

Comment: `jTextArea1.setEnabled(false);
jScrollPane1.setEnabled(false);`

Comment: i meant, post the context of the code. See if you can figure out what the problematic section of code is and post that.

Comment: well i am not sure about that. I have lots of jTextField set to setEnabled(false); they all work fine.

Comment: A JTextField is not the same as a JTextArea. That might be your problem.

Comment: now only i realized that jTextField also have the same problem. jTextField  have a different border which fades when setEnabled is false.

Comment: Also varies by Look & Feel.

Comment: You say you created a GUI with NetBeans and, in you class constructor or something, you set it to disabled?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make the code followed by jTextArea1.setBackground(Color.GREY); So it will look like this.

```
jTextArea1.setEnabled(false); jScrollPane1.setEnabled(false);
jTextArea1.setBackground(Color.GREY);
```